# Why my model's training and validation accuracy remains constant after one epoch? [Keras]

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have 4684 images data of dimension **(4684, 150, 150, 3)** and labels data of dimension **(4684, 8)**. On first epoch, training accuracy is 0.5695 and validation accuracy is 0.7535. After first epoch my model doesn't learn and its training and validation accuracy remains constant. So, What could be the problem? Can you guys help me?

This is my model.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(kernel_size=(3,3),filters=8,input_shape=(150, 150, 3),activation="relu",padding="valid"))
model.add(Conv2D(kernel_size=(3,3),filters=8,activation="relu",padding="same"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.6))
model.add(Dense(100,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(8,activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

X = model.fit(data,labels,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          shuffle=True,
          validation_split=0.2)

plt.plot(X.history['loss'])
plt.plot(X.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image: Model Loss]

Answer (score 1):

Can I ask you, are the labels converted to categorical?

And two, please change the optimizer Adam to SGD with lr = .1

And three, please remove same in Conv2D layer or add more Conv2D + MaxPooling2D layer to model

Comment: yes the labels are converted into categorical.
labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(labels, 8)

Comment: just tried what you said. but still getting same training and validation accuracy.

Comment: Oh, you only used 8 filters. Change them to 128 and 64! I hope this time works properly :)

Comment: Thank You amin. It worked. 
I added some more conv2D layers and filters. And it wasn't learning with SGD, but when i used Adam again, its learning now.

Comment: Very well. Good luck my friend :)